# WebPart UpdatePanel namespace missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I'm creating a web part. I need an update panel to refresh controls when using dropdowns list. I dont know why but it's missing the namespace when it shouldnt right?

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        updatePanel2 = new UpdatePanel();
        updatePanel2.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;

        toolPartPanel = new Panel();
        label2 = new Label();
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact text of the error you're seeing?

Comment: yes of course. the error is: "The type or namespace name 'UpdatePanel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly referece?)"

Answer (score 2):

I'm creating a web part too. When I try to use an update panel to refresh controls i get the same error in the autogenerated code.

To fix it, I have added a new reference to the project.

When I add `System.Web.Extensions` to the references and rebuild the project, the problem disappear.

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your project's references, have you included a reference to System.Web.UI?  Usually when it doesn't give you the option to resolve it's because the DLL reference is missing.

Comment: I cant see System.Web.UI on the list to add references. There's a lot of System.Web..something but not UI.

Comment: Well, it may already be added--do you see it in the list of references?

Comment: ye, i was using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls and others. Now i just added System.Web.UI and it seems fine. Thank you! It is strange that such a simple thing and Visual Studio could suggest me a namespace like it does most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top.

```
using System.Web.UI
```

The control was not where you thought it would be. You can check the namespace in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx

Or if you're using Visual Studio, hover your mouse over the UpdatePanel word and it will suggest options for resolving the namespace.

Comment: i did that but its the same. I know about that solution, usually you just have to mouseover > resolve and add the suggested. But this one doesnt appear anything.